# Is it reliable to integrate google charts with AngularJS this way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I have searched on StackOverflow, most people suggest to bootstrap the app after loading google charts ([Demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kGUhDM?p=preview)), that is

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
});
```

Personally, I don't like this solution much, since the app may fail to bootstrap when google charts fail to load.

and in **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n77wA/32/light/)**, he (I couldn't find the name, sorry) used a different approach, which I really like.

Yet I wonder whether it's reliable, the demo watch $attr.data and then init the charts, but what if google charts is not ready when $attr.data is available? Will that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is already created directive for google charts you should consider looking at this  library http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/.